# How define non-Eco attribute?

Tags: mdriven

I need to define som (transient) fields & properties in Eco classes that aren't supported by the Eco framework.

**Q:** How do I define a field/attribute as "non-Eco" in an Eco class?

Example:

```
Brep[] SolidHousing; // An array of CAD faces & boxes
```

//Rolf

Answer (score 0):

You can add transient attributs in dem Modlr but they are also treated by MDriven as attributes and MDriven does not allow arrays, dictionaries or lists in the Modlr.

What you can do is: Simply add them in the .cs file of your class. Don't touch the .eco.cs class but you can do anything you want in the .cs file. Please keep in mind that the class has a generated constructor and that you can add logic in the constructor by implementing the ObjectCreated() partial method. When you take a look into the code in the .eco.cs file, you will understand.

Hint: Normally it's no good idea to add an own constructor without using the Modlr for it.

Already generated constructor:

```
[GeneratedCodeAttribute("ECO", "7.1.0.0")]
public YourClass(Eco.ObjectRepresentation.IEcoServiceProvider serviceProvider) : 
    base(serviceProvider) {
  try {
    this.ObjectCreated();
  }
  catch (System.Exception ) {
    this.Deinitialize(serviceProvider);
    throw;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok.Problem is of course that in my case the non-eco fields are among the most essential information about the class that there is.

I think that in BoldForDelphi (I know, those were the days) I could visibly define non-bold attributes in the model. This would be a valuable addition to the EcoModeler as well. It could just spit out the type and then disregard the rest of the generation process. 

There is need also for "regular" C# getters and setters for non-eco property types. The Eco "infrastructure" would be valuable, but on top of that I make temporary objects with lots of computations

Comment: MDiven attributes (properties) can be persistent and transient. Transient properties by themselves can be simply transient, but also derived (calculated) and reverse derived (calculated but also setable). All those attributes get full MDriven support e.g. for databinding. But MDriven sticks to the UML standard which means that the type of these attributes is restricted. It cant be a different modeled object cause this would be an association but you can model it as such. So your Brep[] could be a transient 0..* association to class Brep, if Brep is part of your model.

Comment: A Brep in my case is a Rhino3d class which is not part of the Eco model, so I'm back at requesting plain non-eco fields & properties.

https://mcneel.github.io/rhinocommon-api-docs/api/RhinoCommon/html/T_Rhino_Geometry_Brep.htm

I understand that EcoSpace can't handle alien types, but the solution is to allow it in the model but disregard any handling of them. The Eco ancestor Bold Architecture handled non-Bold fields with the deepest respect (by code-generating them, but not touching them after that). Meant that they were valuable visible model information, a main point with a model...;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are some possibilities you could try. Do you want your Brep data to be persisted? If so, you could write a custom persistence mapper so that this type could get generated and persisted.
You cannot model a property of type Brep[] but if you model a transient class Brep, you could add a transient 0..* association to this class which would get a IEcoList which is similar.
But the easiest way would be to forget about the model and manually add the Brep[] field or property by hand in the .cs file.

Comment: When need for persistent objects (not very often in my case) any Brep objecta are persisted inside Rhino. So in those cases I could model a EcoBrepRef class which only stores the Brep guid(s)  and with that a link-member-event should be able to retrieve the specific Rhino.Geometry.Brep object(s) from the Rhino Api. Something along those lines. This is why I don't think the Eco Framework should complain about the the Brep[] type or any other alien type really. But yes, I could do stuff under the model-hood directly in the partial class but... it's not so eco-friendly... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Peter Buchman's answers are good suggestions.

One of the reasons the MDriven framework don't support non-eco style types is that it usually leads down the rabbit hole to non-modelled storage patterns. An array is better served with an association as Peter writes. Of course one can argue that adding support for it wouldn't hurt, but then that also need support, taking time away from more pressing things.

That said, I would suggest the following ways to solve your issues.

1. Add simple attributes in the .cs class as Peter suggests.
2. Maybe make the array into an List<> if that would work for your other code to work with.
3. Implement list manipulation code for your specific needs supporting the Brep[] usage, by having code that acts on the modelled multi-association when accessing the Brep[].

Comment: If it were only one type... (see link below), but it's potentially hundreds of types. One reason for using eco-approach in my case would be the insane speed you can achieve in complex (geometry) models if you don't have to redraw everything from scratch when only a few parameters change. With Attracs I learnt what can be done if subscribing following a certain pattern. Anyway, some of the types I'll cache with "smart properties" are listed here: https://mcneel.github.io/rhinocommon-api-docs/api/RhinoCommon/html/N_Rhino_Geometry.htm (for now I handcraft a "poor man's bold/eco" for this case).

Comment: I recall using code snippets autogenerating "dirty flags" for regular Delphi attributes with Bold. Like, having a pascal property "SomeName" with a corresponding Bold member "SomeName_IsDirty: Boolean" which provided subscription support for the otherwise unsupported Delphi fields/properties. Extremely powerful, and simple when using code-snippet templates. In most cases I use transient attributes, no need for persistence, instead, as I indicated, I'm aiming för super fast algorithms (by reducing the need for recreating stuff on parameter changes). I know what I'm doing, and why.